# trigger colorbox resize on parsley validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK so basically I am using parsley.js validate and colorbox to submit a form via ajax

The problem I am facing is that I cannot figure out how to resize the colorbox dynamically when the validation errors appear.I would like to trigger this function when pasreley loads in the errors.

```
$.colorbox.resize();
```

This is what the form submit code looks like

```
   $("#form").submit(function(e)
    {

        if ( $(this).parsley('validate')) {

            var postData = new FormData(this);

            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

            $.ajax({});
        }; 

        e.preventDefault();

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(){$.colorbox.resize();})
```

If you wish to handle the error event.
See official documentation to know the event which you want to handle.
http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-events-list

Comment: doesn't seem to work.. how exactly would that look with my script?

Comment: Where does the line you specified get added into the post function?

Comment: you should have it inside your $(document).ready(function(){/* add here */})

Comment: I was getting an undefined function error, but then I realized I was using an older version of parsley, but your guidance to add a listener worked. Thanks